# zsh tab complete . to ./

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

> *Not a duplicate:*
>   I'm not looking for a way to complete directory names or execute scripts from a fixed directory. The issue I'm trying to solve is to get completion for the *current* directory *without* pressing <kbd>/</kbd>

---

I want zsh to tab-complete `.` to `./` like bash.

With bash I'm used to press <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to see all files in the *current working directory* since it first completes to `./` and then shows all content in that directory. Reason for my desire to avoid <kbd>/</kbd> at all cost is that <kbd>/</kbd> is way harder on my german keyboard than <kbd>TAB</kbd> since it's either with 2 fingers with shift or far away on numpad and I'd rather switch back to bash than type a `/`. What I'd like to achieve, in other words what bash does:

```
$ .               <TAB>
$ ./              <TAB>
foo.sh   somedir/
$ ./              <F><TAB>
$ ./foo.sh        <ENTER>
```

Using zsh / oh-my-zsh when I hit <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> I get `.` (dot space) which is not useful at all for me.

- Using `zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true` with `setopt auto_cd` (which is oh-my-zsh default) gives me the even less useful option for `../` on top, so I turned that off already. I'm happy with completion of `cd`.
- There is no `.` on `$PATH` and it should stay that way. Though I wouldn't mind completion of e.g. `f<TAB>` to `./foo.sh` for example.

How can I teach zsh to complete `.` to `./` or even better to local directory content right away? Or is there another way to work with local script files in an efficient way that does not involve <kbd>/</kbd>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zsh autocomplete directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/zsh-autocomplete-directory)

Comment: @Sparhawk No, not really my issue or a solution to it.

Comment: in `bash` you are getting `foo.sh` as one if suggestion is because that's executable otherwise that is out. you can check the code of bash-completion to see what is does and maybe you can simulate the same in zsh

Comment: @αғsнιη the issue is not that zsh won't complete executables once you're at `./`, it's that it doesn't get there from `.` - There's surely a simple regex rules one can put somewhere that triggers for exactly the string `.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great challenge!
Try this on the commandline, if it works add it to ~/.zshrc

```
bindkey '^I' dotcomplete
zle -N dotcomplete
```

```
function dotcomplete() {                                        
  if [[ $BUFFER =~ ^'\.'$ ]]; then
    BUFFER='./'
    CURSOR=2
    zle list-choices
  else
    zle expand-or-complete
  fi
}
```

It adds a function which runs every time you press TAB (^I).  If the the line you've currently typed only contains a dot (^=beginning of line, '\.' =super-escape the dot, $=end of line), then replace that dot with a ./ then continue with the normal completion.

It doesn't exactly do what you ask, which is to treat the dot as the current directory.  But it will save you they keystrokes you want to save.

Comment: This works great! Changed regex to `if [[ $BUFFER =~ ^'\.'$ ]]; then` (`$` at the end) so it doesn't act on `./foo<TAB>`. Also had to add the line `zle -N dotcomplete` to my `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

given your `f<TAB>` option/workaround, I present:

```
$ function f(){ local x=$1; shift; ./"$x" "$@"; }
$ f foo<TAB>
```

notice the space after <kbd>f</kbd> in that last line

Comment: Nice. While I don't have that `f<TAB>` workaround, this still works because `f<SPACE><TAB>` suggests local directory files and selecting one will correctly execute it. A little odd to remember `f` (or whatever name that function gets) though.

Comment: yes, I only used 'f' because you had it, but perhaps 'x' ("execute") would be better